# What is the Latin translation for the "reply or your mother will die" meme?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, sentence-translation

What is the Latin translation of the meme,

> Reply to this post or your mother will die in her sleep tonight.

I intend to put it in a *lorem ipsum* to see if anyone notices. I know *lorem ipsum* texts are often very bad or even outright fake Latin, so a loose translation is acceptable. I tried machine translation, but the entire sentence structure changes depending on which English word I substitute for the anachronistic *post*.

Answer (score 5):

First, to note, lorem ipsum text isn't really Latin at all—it's based on a Latin source, but heavily mutilated to make it look vaguely English at a casual glance.

However, for a translation, I would say:

> nisi huic respondebis mater tua peribit

Or, with nicer punctuation:

> Nisi huic respondebis, mater tua peribit.
>   *Unless you respond to this, your mother will die.*

I would use the unpunctuated version if you want to hide it in a long stream of text, though.

Comment: Could future-perfect "responderis" be used, indicating that one thing will have to be completed before the consequence is invoked? In conditional sentences (simple/ open conditions) this fut. perf./ future linkage is often observed e.g. "si veneris, eum videbis". But, as in your example, sometimes, less frequently, future/ future e.g. "si recto cursu Romam petemus hac nocte in Capitolio epulabimur." Does this subtle difference matter;  may the student choose freely?

Comment: @tony Good question! I was taught that it was more common to use the simple future here, but I'm not sure if that's actually how it works.

Comment: Allen & Greenough p516 (p326, reprint) in "Future Conditions" give good information, on this.

Comment: Rarer still, a double future-perfect: North & Hillard Ex. 206; Q3: "Unless you remind him, he will have forgotten in three days." = "nisi eum admonueris, tribus diebus oblitus erit.".  The timeline, second clause, provides the scope for the fut. perf. (I got that one wrong!)

Answer (score 1):

Responde nuntium, aliter tua mater in cubiculo nocte morietur.

This phrase reads:
"Answer this message, otherwise your mother will die in bed during the night."